# Returning array[] from void, C

Tags: c, arrays, void

So when I write a function

```
void sort (int oldarray[], int length)
{

//imagine there is a function here that runs a loop and finishes with a sorted:

newarray[];
}
```

How do I get newarray[] to replace oldarray[] in the main function that could look like this:

```
int main()
{
int length = 7
int oldarray[length]

//here would be a loop that populates the oldarray

sort(oldarray[], length)

//a loop that prints the newarray[] from the sort or main function
}
```

FYI this isn't homework. I'm teaching myself, so you aren't helping me cheat a professor out of their hard earned money.

Comment: If you don't sort in-place, you can `memcpy` the sorted array to the original.

Comment: Why you would want to replace an array, if you already have one? You can operate on `oldarray[]` elements.

Comment: but won't it (newarray that is) be out of scope in main() in the way it is defined now?

Comment: If you don't want to return it from function, make `newarray` global.

Comment: Daniel's suggestion of `memcpy` is correct. But is there a reason you want `sort()` to be void instead of returning `newarray` and assigning `oldarray = sort(oldarray, length);`?

Comment: It was listed that way in the book I'm using. So I figured there must be something I'm missing. I also did change it to `int sort()` and had it `return newarray` but that gave me an error or returned only one number, I can't remember.

Also the reason why I would replace the old array with a new one is b/c the old array is unsorted and the new array is sorted.

Thanks guise.

Comment: That makes sense. I was just curious. In the case where you did return `newarray`, you would want `sort()` to be defined as `int[] sort(...)` . Just for future reference.

Comment: for some reason my compiler says its expecting `"(" for (...) instead of "["`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is based on Aniket's answer, but simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void sort (int *oldarray, int *newarray, int length)
{
    // do your stuff, and put result in newarray
}

int main()
{
    int length = 7;
    int oldarray[length];
    int newarray[length];

    // here would be a loop that populates the oldarray

    sort(oldarray, newarray, length);

    // a loop that prints the newarray from the sort or main function

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void sort (int *oldarray, int length, int *newarray, int *newlength)
{

//imagine there is a function here that runs a loop and finishes with a sorted:

//newarray after sorting can be passed to `main` function - even if the function returns void
// also remember to set the `newlength`
}

int main()
{
  int newlength;
  int *newarray = malloc(7 * sizeof(int));
  int length = 7
  int oldarray[length]

  //here would be a loop that populates the oldarray

  sort(oldarray[], length, newarray, &newlength)

  //a loop that prints the newarray[] from the sort or main function
  free(newarray);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if you pass in a pointer as an argument, it will be returned or changed in the `main` function?

Comment: @user2208569, what Aniket wanted to tell is that pointers are static, they point to the fixed memory location, while you actually can change stuff that they point to.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to put [] on your call to sort:

```
sort(oldarray, length)
```

If you really don't want to return anything from the sort function instead of passing in an array, which is really just a pointer, you want to pass in a pointer to a pointer and then re-assign what the pointer points to (phew). Like so:

```
int ** pointer_to_arr = &old; //& gives address of old
sort(pointer_to_arr, length);
```

In sort:

```
sort(int** arr, int len) {
    //you need to malloc the new array if you don't want it
    //to go away on function return:
    int* new_array = (int*) malloc(len*sizeof(int));
    //... sort here into new_array ...
    *arr = new_array; //set arr to the newly sorted array 
}
```

You can now access new_array from pointer_to_old:

```
int* new_array = *pointer_to_arr;
 //... do what you will
//don't forget to release you memory when you're done
free (new_array);
```